# Mirror Github Enterprise repository in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure DevOps repository

Tags: devops, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, github-enterprise

Is there a way to Mirror a repository hosted in **Github Enterprise** in an Oracle Cloud Infrastructure DevOps project? By default Oracle Cloud Infrastructure allows mirroring from github.com or gitlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question, I am a Product Manager at Oracle Cloud working on DevOps ... we support mirroring (pull from Oracle DevOps) for the cloud versions of GitLab.com and GitHub.com and we're looking to support mirroring from GitHub Enterprise - its in our roadmap

For now, I'd suggest you setup a mirror of your GitHub Enterprise repo: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository to a new OCI DevOps code repository using OCI auth (https or ssl)

then write a cron job to periodically push updates

Comment: Thanks very much for this information @jonschreiber . I'll give this approach a try. However, is there a place where I can get updates on mirroring support for GitHub enterprise?

Comment: Hi Somesh! Yes for sure, updates to OCI services will go into release notes so check in to this page: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/releasenotes/services/devops/

As well it will show up as a new Connection type in the API/SDK and UI. Since we know you're interested, we can let you know directly, too!